# Laravel Mollie payment - 419 Page Expired

Tags: laravel

I am new to the Mollie API and I am trying to prepare a new payment. Therefore I have a form with a order id, order total and invoice number. Here the code of this form:

```xml
<form action="{{ route('payInvoice') }}" method="POST">
  @csrf
  <input type="text" name="invoice_id" value="{{ $invoice->id }}" hidden>
  <input type="text" name="order_total" value="{{ $order->total_price }}" hidden>
  <input type="text" name="order_number" value="{{ $order->number}}" hidden>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-icon icon-left"><i class="fas fa-credit-card"></i> Factuur betalen</button>
</form>
```

The web.php:

```php
Route::post('/pay-invoice', [App\Http\Controllers\MollieController::class, 'preparePayment'])->name('payInvoice');
```

The MollieController preparePayment class:

```php
public function preparePayment(Request $request)
{
    $invoice_id = $request->get('invoice_id');
    $order_total = $request->get('order_total');
    $order_number = $request->get('order_number');
    
    $payment = Mollie::api()->payments()->create([
        'amount' => [
            'currency' => 'EUR',
            'value' =>  $order_total,
        ],
        'description' => 'Betaling voor factuur' . $invoice_id,
        'redirectUrl' => route('showInvoice', 1),
        'webhookUrl'   => route('webhooks.mollie'),
        'metadata' => [
            'order_id' => $order_number,
        ]
    ]);
    
    $payment = Mollie::api()->payments()->get($payment->id);
    
    return redirect($payment->getCheckoutUrl(), 303);
}
```

When I click on the button, I get a 419 Page Expired error.

Anyone who can help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I turned on the debug bar. It says:

CSRF Token mismatch.

Comment: can you mention laravel version.? also try to clear cache and run php artisan key:generate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to add the `showInvoice` (redirect url) route to the exceptions in your `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware's `$except` array.

```php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        route('showInvoice'),
    ];
}
```